# CSS Pseudo Active : Why wont :active background position shift wont work in IE?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, button, pseudo-class

**EXAMPLE :** http://jsfiddle.net/9BygQ/5/

If you test the example in Chrome you will see that on :active the button appears pressed in. **Why does the active pseudo state not seem to have any effect in IE?**

This problem has been bothering me for a while now...

Love some help!

Cheers

Comment: You might wanna have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9

Answer (score 0):

Here's at least a hint:

you might have seen that on IE the :active triggers on the right side of the button. i.e. the 10px padding-right area. So it seems that while your `<span>` is above your `<a>`, IE will activate the :hover but not the :active. (i may be wrong, i found this behaviour only by clicking everywhere :)  )

So i tried to reverse `<a>` and `<span>` and it's almost working (still have a problem with the image right side)

Here is the new code

`HTML <a><span>SEXY BUTTON</a></span></a>`

```
CSS span  a{  background:url('http://thebeer.co/imgs/UI/sprite.png') right -548px  no-repeat; padding-right:10px;  color:#CCC; font-size:12px;}

span{width:200px;display:block;background:url('http://thebeer.co/imgs/UI/sprite.png') -1348px -475px  no-repeat; padding:10px 11px;  padding-right:2px; text-align:center; font-family:medium; text-transform:uppercase; letter-spacing:1px;}

a:hover{color:#F97216;}
a:active{background-position:right -584px; color:#666;  cursor:pointer;}
a:active > span  {background-position:-1348px  -511px ;}
```

I'm not sure this will solve your problem but i hope it will help :)