# css active doesn't do mouse release in IE9

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

The image stays put when I depress my mouse in IE9. I have to click an other part of the page to get it back up. Firefox and Chrome work fine (they put back the original image). Any ideas?

It even works here if I use IE9
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro

But not if I create an html on my desktop and open it in IE9.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
  #button{background:url("http://www.webstuffshare.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/button3.jpg") no-repeat 0 0;display:block;width:201px;height:67px;}
  #button:hover{background-position:0px -67px;}
  #button:active{background-position:0px -134px;}
  #button span{position:absolute;top:-99999999em;}
</style>    
</head>
<body>
  <a id="button" href="#"><span>this is foo</span></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must click off of the object in order for it to remove it's active state.

Comment: The behavior I am seeing is that if I am still "over" the button when I release the mouse it works, however, in all three browsers (IE9, FF12, Chrome), if I press, hold mouse button down and move off the button, it keeps the "pressed" state. Chrome corrected it once I just moved the mouse again after lifting, Firefox and IE9 seemed to require another click in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your better off using js events as `:active` can behave unintuitively (similar issue; [:active css selector not working for IE8 and IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9))

One way to bodge the behaviour you want would be to;

```
<a id="button" href="#" onclick="this.blur();" onmouseout="this.blur();"><span>this is foo</span></a>
```