# Anchor with span insite - in IE9 doesn't working

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, anchor, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [:active css selector not working for IE8 and IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9)

I have following problem. I have my stylised linkbutton with span inside (asp.net)

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" CssClass="button"><span><%# Resources.Resource.BUTTON_SEND %></span></asp:LinkButton> <br />
```

And in CSS:

```
.button 
{
background: transparent url(../Images/button/button_right.png) no-repeat scroll top right;
color: #444;
display: block;
float: left;
font: normal 12px arial, sans-serif;
height: 34px;
margin-right: 6px;
padding-right: 11px; /* sliding doors padding */
text-decoration: none;  
}

.button  span
{  
background: transparent url(../Images/button/button_left.png) no-repeat;
display: block;
line-height: 14px;
padding: 10px 0 10px 12px;
color: #BFD7FF;
}

.button:active 
{
background-position: bottom right;
color: #000;
outline: none; /* hide dotted outline in Firefox */
}

.button:active  span
{   
background-position: bottom left;
padding: 11px 0 9px 12px; /* push text down 1px */
color: White;
}
```

there are my images:
[image: image1]
[image: image2]

In firefox, chrome work fine, but in IE9 :active not trigger. Is any trick to make it work correctly?

Best regards,
Dagna

Comment: It looks like this topic may have been covered before, check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5594102/active-css-selector-not-working-for-ie8-and-ie9

Comment: can you upload button_left.png,button_right.png ?