# CSS :active selector ignores the state of child elements in IE

Tags: css, css-selectors

In Webkit browsers, the CSS `:active` selector seems to also work if the child element was in active state. On the other hand, IE browsers (I've tested with IE 10 and 11) ignores the state of children.

Here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9pd97/).

If you click on the image in IE, nothing happens. In Chrome, the CSS rules for `li:active` and `li:active > img` are applied.

How can I get the same behavior in IE using only CSS/CSS3?

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/a/5594589/1256925 and especially http://stackoverflow.com/a/17211251/1256925 are relevant to this question.

Comment: Assuming this is a rendering bug, I highly doubt there any solutions in pure CSS. If there were a parent selector, there would be a work-around, however that currently isn't the case. Always something, IE.. Nice find :)

Comment: @JoshC I don't think there's a pure CSS solution to this either, but atleast there's a workaround (although it does also changes the way it looks). I agree though, nice find. Even though IE10/11 are a LOT better than the previous versions, there's still a lot that does go wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do this is instead of using nested `<img>` tags, just use `background-image`. You can then just set the `background-position` so that the `background-image` is in the correct place, and then apply the styles you want to the `li` itself. For example, you could do [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/9pd97/2/):

```
li {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:10px 10px;
}

li:active {
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    opacity:0.3;
}
```

I've used inline styles in that demo for the `background-image` and `width/height` styles, because I assume you'll want to use different images for each `li`.

This workaround may not work exactly the same as the original, but nobody said making your site work for IE was without cost.

Comment: This is a great idea. I cannot modify the structure of the HTML, so it is not the exact answer I am looking for. But it really seems like I need to change the HTML, or use JavaScript. If there are no better answers, I will accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This can also be fixed by placing a pseudo element layer on the `<li>` above the `<img>` like so:

```
li {
    position: relative;
}

li:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The pseudo element is part of the `<li>` so the click will occur on the `<li>` and not the `<img>` triggering the :active state for the child items. For more info: [see this post](http://briantree.se/fixing-active-pseudo-class-selector-internet-explorer/)