# Active state pseudo class and Adjacent element selector combined on IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer, css-selectors

I'm currently having an issue with this on IE - http://jsbin.com/riyaxewo/4

**HTML**

```
<div class="a">
  1
</div>
<div class="b">
  2
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.a, .b {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border: 1px solid;
  text-align: center;
}
.a:active, .b:active {
  background-color: red;
}
.a:hover + .b {
  background-color: transparent;
}
.a:active + .b {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

The expected result is for box #2 to be yellow whenever box #1 is pressed, however, on IE this
effect only occurs once, and then it just wont happen again.

The reason I'm doing this in CSS and not programatically is because I want the effect to take place as long as the mouse was pressed on the element, even if the mouse button was released somewhere else (meaning I can't rely on `mouseup`, and `mouseleave/mouseout` will not get me the wanted result)

Comment: Managed to solve this using jquery and event namespaceing - http://jsbin.com/riyaxewo/11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17211251/3884420

apparently its a bug in IE and its the same for children of active elements and anything like that. you could try a js script that uses on mousedown and on mouseup triggers. I know you said you can't.

also something even funnier happened while testing your problem. if you try to leave your mouse while active it works every time. I removed hover property you added and even this stopped working. I'm guessing every time that your mouse leaves and hover effect stops, the active effect fires again.

Comment: thanks! actually I did manage to solve this issue using jquery I've updated the question with the solution